# wdPasteText pasting as image on Word

Tags: excel, vba, ms-word

I am very close to finally completing this code I have been working on but I have hit a bit of a snag. I  need the selected to be pasted as plain text onto a word document, however, with my current code, it pastes the selected as an image.

```
Sub CopyRangeToWord()
 Dim objWord
 Dim objDoc

Set objWord = CreateObject("Word.Application")
Set objDoc = objWord.Documents.Add

Sheets("Executive Outline").Range("B5:B220").Select
Selection.Copy

With objWord
    .Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=wdPasteText, _
    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
End With
objWord.Visible = True
End Sub
```

Can someone please let me know where I am going wrong? I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution here is to use this code:

```
.Selection.PasteSpecial Link:=False, DataType:=2, _
    Placement:=wdInLine, DisplayAsIcon:=False
```

**Short explanation...:**

You are working with Late Bindings and without `Option Explicit` statement. Therefore all `MS Word constants` like `wdPasteText`, `wdInLine` are considered as variables with not declared values. Therefore you have `0` for both constants. Solutions:

1. use `early binding` to keep `text constants`
2. always use `Option Explicit` to avoid such problems
3. for `late binding` always use numeric values instead of text constants.

Comment: Thank you very much! Just the code I've been looking for